# How to display value in sql request with a link in Dropdown

Tags: mysql

I have this sql request:

```
 SELECT LEFT("Libelle", 10) as lib, "LRU", "Client", 
round(sum("Montant_fac_eur")) as ca from "foundry_sync"."/Users/Data/detfactsam16_17_Données-master" 
    where "Nature"='Repair' 
    and "annee" = {{w_widget18.selectedValue}}
    and extract(month from "Facturation") 
between {{w_widget35.selectedValue}} +0 and {{w_widget35.selectedValue}} +5
    group by lib,"LRU", "Client"
```

When I run it, the parameters `lib` it return `null`, when I comment this line `and "annee" = {{w_widget18.selectedValue}}` it return the all the value of the `lib`

Can you tell me please where's the problem ?
Thank you

Comment: `{{w_widget18.selectedValue}}` or `{{w_widget35.selectedValue}} +0 and {{w_widget35.selectedValue}} +5`  doesnt look like it's valid SQL

Comment: I'm sorry, but it return the best values when I compare them by the original source in my Excel file.